# Docker hello-world gives error that container /hello: no such file or directory": unknown

Tags: docker, containers, centos7

I am new on Docker and try to understand how it works. I installed docker to virtualbox centos 7  instance. The service is working properly but when I run hello-world image it gives following error .

```
 [root@localhost ~]# docker run hello-world
    docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/hello\":
stat /hello: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

I tried $ docker system prune but didn't work again. Here is all command line history that includes system information and docker information.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

[root@localhost ~]# docker --version
Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
[root@localhost ~]# docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/hello\": stat /hello: no such file or directory": unknown.

[root@localhost ~]# docker system prune
WARNING! This will remove:
        - all stopped containers
        - all networks not used by at least one container
        - all dangling images
        - all dangling build cache
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Containers:
ace04702bb0e2a1997dc35a0a21c7ca49a395809e5d1da98ddc99ee16544dcc4
e70f5999470577d0eca655643b7ba2ce41ee99495bb257d8ca5f956c26a7079b
82f65c36f76cf2cbf6297a514865d45524bf3cb4472be5e5da72c632cd535a3b

Total reclaimed space: 0B
[root@localhost ~]# docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/hello\": stat /hello: no such file or directory": unknown.
[root@localhost ~]# docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 18.09.3
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: e6b3f5632f50dbc4e9cb6288d911bf4f5e95b18e
runc version: 6635b4f0c6af3810594d2770f662f34ddc15b40d
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.701GiB
Name: localhost.localdomain
ID: R2XU:6ZAF:2UZO:QBUR:GGWW:GFIG:DHVF:5DZG:DPG2:GIKV:3GE5:NLS2
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

Comment: Can you try to pull the latest version of this image: `docker pull hello-world` and try again?

Comment: yes I did error again Here console output :                                   [root@localhost ~]# docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
Digest: sha256:2557e3c07ed1e38f26e389462d03ed943586f744621577a99efb77324b0fe535
Status: Image is up to date for hello-world:latest
[root@localhost ~]# docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/hello\": stat /hello: no such file or directory": unknown.
[root@localhost ~]#

Comment: Others work well `[root@localhost ~]# docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
...
Digest: sha256:98efe605f61725fd817ea69521b0eeb32bef007af0e3d0aeb6258c6e6fe7fc1a
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
60c637cc1f94ea264a306f350de8f89397a6c6345e891669443cd8aab79c3be2
[root@localhost ~]# curl http://localhost
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

Comment: I am wondering if you don't have an hidden character that you copy/pasted somehow. Have you tried **manually** retyping the exact same command?

Comment: You may try `docker image save hello-world:latest > hello-world.tar` and see if `layer.tar` inside the `hello-world.tar` has `hello` binary.

Comment: b.enoit.be I just copied the shell all command syntax is valid

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `docker image inspect hello-world:latest`

Comment: I get error when I try to save image with  "docker image inspect hello-world:latest" . please check console output that includes docker image inspect : http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NwyNy2FFhZ

Comment: I am curios of the CentOS version. What is the output of `rpm -q centos-release`? If it is older than 7.4, you need to update the package of `libseccomp` according the [Divvya Metha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10182375/divvya-mehta)'s link on GitHub.

Comment: Here is the output of rpm -q centos-release :         [root@localhost ~]# rpm -q centos-release
centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

this is causing because of old version of CentOS.
Check https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35906
Please upgrade your CentOS to 7.4.

Comment: As you see I am using centos newest 7.6 version 
Here is the output of rpm -q centos-release : [root@localhost ~]# rpm -q centos-release centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

After reading some documentation  acknowledged that this issue has not occurred from docker but **selinux** configuration. It recommended that *#sestatus Current Mode* should be **permissive** but it was  **enforcing** in my case. I think this makes all error halts process rather than logging. So

```
#setenforce 0  
#docker system prune -a
```

it works!

Thanks for all help on this issue.